# Linear probing and tabulation hashing

Tags: data-structures, hash-tables, hashing

I'm currently reading the paper "The Power of Simple Tabulation Hashing" by Mihai Patrascu and Mikkel Thorup [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.5200)] because I want to adapt the proof of the constant time complexity of linear probing for modified tabulation hashing. I would like to ask a question about Corollary 11 (page 17).
In this corollary is shown that $Pr[R \ge l] \le 2^{-\Omega(l\epsilon^2)} + (l/m)^\gamma$ for
$\alpha \ge 1/2$ and  $Pr[R \ge l] \le \alpha^{\Omega(l)} + (l/m)^\gamma$ for
$\alpha \le 1/2$ when $\gamma = O(1)$ and $l \le n^{1/(3c)}/\alpha$.
Here R is the length of the run during linear probing and $c \ge 1$.

Then as I understand, we can prove that $E[R] = O(1/\epsilon^2)$
using the formula $E[X] = \sum_{l=1}^{n} Pr[X \ge l]$. Could you please explain
how do we apply the last formula if $l > n^{1/(3c)}/\alpha$?
Intuitively, I understand that we have a tight concentration around $O(1/\epsilon^2)$
and, thus, the expectation is around it. 
But how do we take into account that $l$ can be greater than $n^{1/(3c)}/\alpha$ when showing that $E[R] = O(1/\epsilon^2)$?
Moreover,  what if $1/\epsilon^2 > n^{1/(3c)}/\alpha$?
Then how do we prove that $E[R] = O(1/\epsilon^2)$?

Thank you very much for you help.